# trying to cretae a login using php

Tags: php, mysql

When I store email and password in database and then post same email and password it matches with latest inserted email and password; if I try to login with another email and password that was inserted previously it shows an error.

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';
  if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      if($mail==$data['email'] && $pwd==$data['password']) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pwd;
        header("location:home.php");
      } else {
        header("location:bhag.php");
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You'd need a WHERE statement in your query. As it stands the current query selects the latest entry in the database, hence it will select the latest username/password combination introduced. And it will work, if it so happens that the username/password combo is, by chance, the latest registered. Also shame on the people who downvoted you, apparently they weren't newbies once.

Comment: Dont store passwords without hashing.

Comment: Please do not use Stackoverflow to ask questions about debugging such code. Instead consult you local computer book seller to find some lecture you can start with. It starts with throwing what you have so far away and start over from scratch with a clear mind and resources that guide you along the way. Don't throw the experience away, that it didn't work. I think it's important you made this step. So please don't get me wrong.

Comment: wow that's some ugly code... seriously even if you fix your bug, dont ever deploy this on production. Saving passwords in plain text is very bad, and seeing this I have the feeling that might not be the only huge flaw...

Comment: @Bartdude The code has been edited for clarity by JRulle. This guy's clearly new at this. We, as in the "gods" who browse SO should cut him some slack and point him towards some tutorials or, as crazy as this sounds, explain what's wrong with the code instead of making witty comments.

Comment: @AndreiP. thanku for ur support.. i want to learn and it wont matter if they downvoted me :)

Comment: @AndreiP : Well how can I explain better than "saving password in plain text is bad" in a comment ? That's already a lot of key terms to search for best practices. I think your comment is more appropriate towards hakre than me... and my reputation hardly defines me as any SO "god". Also I can hardly explain what's wrong with code I don't see and my main concern is about it, as for example I can reasonably assume there's a SQL injection flaw in the user creation form which we don't see...

Comment: @Hassan Murtaza Chattha: Do you prefer to learn in a linear fashion or more the boom bang in out wrong by example style? Which books have you read so far about the topic you would like to learn? How would you describe the topic you would like to learn about?

Comment: @hakre i m new with php, i m not a professional.. i want to learn basics and i will learn what sql injection etc is.. but the point is if i m stuck with basics how could i manage to handle things like storing password with # etc or how to prevent sql injection..

Comment: i m just a guy who knows how to connect with d.b n CRUD.. nothing more.. n in my semester project my instructor wants me to develop something like social website, fb etc.. n while i m investing my tym n mind n when i ask for help from u people, some of u come up with "ugly code" or down vote.. nothing else :/

Comment: @Hassan Murtaza Chattha: By reading about what you do first - before writing the first line. Then understand the code already while you type it. When you then get an error, the computer technically proof-reads your code so it helps you to learn. Keep in mind that debugging is "out of question" on stackoverflow. So as you wonder about the downvotes: This might be because the way you ask the question is discouraged on this website. Please consult the [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information and [examples how you can improve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

> Avoid using mysql_ functions they are  **deprecrated**.
>
> Use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead

The example below uses mysqli_ functions:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['Login'])) 
{   
    //uses mysqli connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $usr, $passwd, $dbname); 
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    /*search the email and passwd via the sql query itself
      to avoid looping through the huge dataresult in your previous code
    */
    $query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log where email='$mail' AND password='$pwd"; 
    $res = $conn->query($query);
    if($res->num_rows >0){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pwd;
        $conn->close();
        header("location:home.php");
    }else{
        $conn->close();
        header("location:bhag.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['Login'])) 
{       $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

$query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
$flag=0;
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($mail==$data['email'] && $pwd==$data['password'])
{
 $flag=1;
 break;
}
}
if($flag==1)
 header("location:home.php");
else
header("location:bhag.php");
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is not proper. Instead of using while loop you can simply pass post variable in the select query.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $query='SELECT email,password FROM fb_log WHERE email = "'.$mail.'" AND password = "'.$pwd.'" '; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
           $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
           $_SESSION['password'] = $pwd;
           header("location:home.php");
    } else {
           header("location:bhag.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to select all data from the 'fb_log' table.

You can select fields conditionally using mysql:

```
$query = "SELECT email,password
          FROM fb_log
          WHERE email = '$mail'
          AND password = 'md5($pwd)'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // You have some result
} else {
    // Result is empty
}
```

I would also recommend that you use mysqli instead of mysql and validate the $_POST data.

Comment: MD5 for password storage? This is 2015, not 1991. May as well just leave the front door unlocked.

Comment: For this specific question this is best practice instead of store password unencrypted. 
My 7th sense sure that currently it is unencrypted.

Comment: No, please read up on MD5 http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure - you are giving the OP bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will keep you busy and you may learn something along the way. Let's take it step by step, or rather line by line.

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';
  if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      if($mail==$data['email'] && $pwd==$data['password']) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pwd;
        header("location:home.php");
      } else {
        header("location:bhag.php");
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

`$query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log";`

This is where your main problem lies. As it stands this query will return all the emails and passwords from the fb_log table. You're looking for one particular entry. This is where you'd a WHERE clause, like so:

`$query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log WHERE email=SOMETHING AND password=SOMETHING";`

I'd recommend using a database abstraction layer such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) but I'd confuse you even further so let's take the SQL Injection prone route and do it like so:

`$query="SELECT email,password FROM fb_log WHERE email=$_POST['email'] AND password=$_POST['password']";`

Now your query will return only the email/password combination you're looking for.

There's a lot wrong with the code above, but don't stress yourself over it for now. Learn the basics and when you feel ready start looking into more advanced topics.

If you feel up to it, have a look [at this tutorial on PDO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtCdk459NFg).

Also, if you're stuck, give me a personal message here, I'll help you out.